# Replace markdown to HTML tags in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to grab the content between two sets of double underscores, and replace it between two underline html tags, but my regex is not quite right.

```
str = "**test**";
str = str_replace(/**(\wd+)**/g, "<b>$1<\/b>", $str);
// Should echo <b>test</b>
```

What I'm missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: `\d+` matches 1 or more decimals. There is no decimal in `**test**`. `str_replace()` does not parse regex at all, only strings. Use `preg_replace()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bear in mind that:

- `str_replace` does not  use regex, you need `preg_replace`
- `/**(\wd+)**/g` is rather a wrong pattern to use in PHP `preg_*` functions as the `g` flag is not supported. More, `\wd+` matches a word char and then one or more `d` chars, you must have tried to match any alphanumeric chars. `(\w+)` is enough to use here. `*` are special regex metacharacters and need escaping.

So  you need to use

```php
<?php

$str = "**test**";
$str = preg_replace('/\*\*(\w+)\*\*/', '<b>$1</b>', $str);
echo $str;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/14VHo).

To match any text between double asterisks, you need

```php
$str = preg_replace('/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/s', '<b>$1</b>', $str);
```

The `s` flag will make `.` also match line break characters.

Comment: I would go for `/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/` to match any text between `**`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Yes, even `'/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/s'`, but I wanted to decypher the original OP intent.

Comment: I think OP is not aware of it, making so many mistakes, even writing variables wrong.